# Biblatex urldate - how to change parenthesis with square brackets

Tags: biblatex

I would like to produce a Reference list for online resource that ends with angular brackets for `urldate`. For example, I would like to have the following example end with "[Accessed 1st Apr. 2016]".

[image]

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,bibstyle=authoryear, sorting=nty, urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen = {Accessed }    
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib} 
@online{Jerald,
author = {Craig D. Jerald},
title = {School culture:'The hidden curriculum'},
year = {2006},
url = {<http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED495013.pdf>},
organization = {The Center for Comprehensive School Reform and            Improvement},
urldate = {2016-04-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Some statement \parencite{Jerald}.

\printbibliography[title={References}]
\end{document}
```

By browsing this site I got the information I need to tweak the following:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

It seems that I should replace `\mkbibparens` with a string that would specify square brackets, but I don't know what string that would be. I should emphasize that I don't want to change brackets style for year of publication or any other usage, just tweak the `urldate` presentation.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `\mkbibbrackets`. Note that in the `title` field of your example you are probably missing a space after the colon and that the URL as given in the `url` field should not contain the additional `<` and `>` characters, if you want angular brackets around the URL then there are other ways to do that.

Comment: BTW `citestyle=authoryear-ibid,bibstyle=authoryear` could be shortened to the completely equivalent, but easier-to-parse `style=authoryear-ibid`.

Comment: That works! I've fixed the other points you have noted and that works as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can get (context sensitive) square brackets with `\mkbibbrackets`. It is the equivalent of `\mkbibparens` and switches the used brackets according to the nesting level.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlseen = {Accessed}    
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@online{Jerald,
  author       = {Craig D. Jerald},
  title        = {School culture: 'The hidden curriculum'},
  year         = {2006},
  url          = {http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED495013.pdf},
  organization = {The Center for Comprehensive School Reform and Improvement},
  urldate      = {2016-04-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some statement \parencite{Jerald}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jerald, Craig D. (2006). School culture: ’The hidden curriculum’. The Center for Comprehensive School Reform and Improvement. url: http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED495013.pdf [Accessed 1st Apr. 2016].]